# Fetching a specific column from SQLAlchemy relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to allow a user block other users in my app. My problem occurs when I want to check if a user has been blocked by the current (logged-in user). How do I check if a particular user is in the blocked list of the current user? My models are below:

```
class User(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'users'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
urid = Column(String(50), unique=True)
full_name = Column(String(100))
...

blockedlist = relationship('Blacklist', primaryjoin='Blacklist.user_id==User.id', back_populates='owner')

class Blacklist(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'blacklist'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
blocked_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
date_blocked = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())

owner = relationship('User', primaryjoin='Blacklist.user_id==User.id', back_populates='blockedlist')
blocked = relationship('User', primaryjoin='Blacklist.blocked_id==User.id')

def __init__(self, user_id, blocked_id):
    self.user_id = user_id
    self.blocked_id = blocked_id
```

Basically, I want to check that a user's id is in the current user's list of blocked id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.any` on a relationship, like so:

```
alice = User(urid='alice', full_name='Alice')
bob = User(urid='bob', full_name='Bob')

session.add(Blacklist(owner=alice, blocked=bob))
session.commit()

bob_blocked_alice = (
    session.query(User.blockedlist.any(blocked_id=alice.id))
    .filter(User.id == bob.id)
    .scalar()
)

print('Did Bob block Alice:', bob_blocked_alice)

alice_blocked_bob = (
    session.query(User.blockedlist.any(blocked_id=bob.id))
    .filter(User.id == alice.id)
    .scalar()
)

print('Did Alice block Bob:', alice_blocked_bob)
```

As an aside, you can simplify your relationships using the `foreign_keys` parameter:

```
blockedlist = relationship('Blacklist', foreign_keys='Blacklist.user_id', back_populates='owner')

owner = relationship('User', foreign_keys=user_id, back_populates='blockedlist')
blocked = relationship('User', foreign_keys=blocked_id)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I forgot to mention that I'm trying to perform the check in my view (Jinja2) file. I'm looping through the list of users and want to display a message if a particular user has been blocked by the current logged in user. I'd be grateful if you can show how to handle this particular scenario